# SQL Server SSL Encryption

Tags: ssl, sql-server-2014

I have an IIS hosted WCF Service that uses SSL encryption. This service makes requests to a SQL Server 2014 database instance. When I make a call to the service the response message is encrypted. So, the connection between the client (browser) and the service is secure. I also want the connection between the service and the SQL Server 2014 database to be secure.

This is where my question comes in. I am not exactly sure how to do this. I read the following article [Enable Encrypted Connections to the Database Engine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191192.aspx) and I was able to successfully add the certificate to the SQL server database engine and changed the **Force Encryption** flag to **True**. But now I am a bit confused as to whether I want to configure the server to accept encrypted connections or the client to request encrypted connections. Based on the scenario I presented above it seems I want the client to request encrypted connections from the SQL Server DB correct? I guess one reason I am confused is because this is ALL happening on my development machine. SQL Server is being hosted there as is the IIS Service.

If someone with experience could maybe clarify that for me I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you haven't restarted the service, then do so to complete the configuration change. It sounds like you applied the change correctly and using a domain or public CA certificate will prevent a man in the middle attack. To verify that the connections are secure, you can use a DMV named sys.dm_exec_connection which should display true for the encrypt_option for all sessions, as below:

```
    select session_id, net_transport, encrypt_option from sys.dm_exec_connections
```

I'm not certain that connections from the host to SQL Server will be encrypted by SSL\TLS since they would be using the shared memory protocol and Windows manages the security of shared memory.